# openni_camera number of topics is huge

Tags: ros, openni, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm using openni and openni2 packages. They work fine but there's lot of topics out there! Is there a way to reduce the number of topics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200817/openni_camera-number-of-topics-is-huge/) by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't looked at openni(1)_launch in a while, but at least in openni2_launch, a lot of those topics should be:

- internal, meaning they are needed for the internal processing (http://wiki.ros.org/rgbd_launch) pipeline (raw_image->...->pointcloud)
- lazy, meaning they are only published if someone is subscribing to them, and not taking up cycles otherwise

Depending on what data you're interested in, you can force-disable certain components of the rgbd_launch pipeline here (https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_launch/blob/indigo-devel/launch/openni2.launch#L40).

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-04**:
Good answers.  openni_launch is much the same in regards to having the ability to force-disable certain components.